# SMMRY API issue with Insufficient Variables

Tags: javascript, http, smmry

This is the code:

```
// Article Summary
var params = {
    host: 'api.smmry.com',
    path: '/',
    body: {
        SM_API_KEY: 'B...',
        SM_URL: 'www.bbc.com/sampleNews'
    }
};
http.get(params, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
    });
});
```

I am trying to provide a working API request, but not able to. Tried to provide the data this way:

```
var params = {
    host: 'api.smmry.com',
    path: '/',
    SM_API_KEY: 'B...',
    SM_URL: 'www.bbc.com/sampleNews'
};
```

Tried:

```
var params = {
    host: 'api.smmry.com',
    path: '/',
    data: {
        SM_API_KEY: 'B...',
        SM_URL: 'www.bbc.com/sampleNews'
    }
};
```

The error I get:

```
{ sm_api_error: 1, sm_api_message: 'INSUFFICIENT VARIABLES' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
    var params = {
        host: 'api.smmry.com',
        path: '/&SM_API_KEY=B...&SM_URL=' + url,
        method: 'POST'
    };
    var req = http.request(params, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });
```